# Could someone explain how chromosomes are counted here?

Tags: genetics, chromosome, gene, allele, cell-division

[image]

I'm not sure how chromosomes are counted in this picture. I would reason that there would be 8 chromosomes in the diploid cell, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Could someone explain?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: In particular, part of the minimum effort expected of posters is that they search on this site for similar questions and then read the associated answers. Here is [one of several examples of what you can find](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/59287/46609).

Comment: Where did the diagram come from?  I'd say it is flat-out wrong, as the left shows 8 chromosomes. It shows 4 _types_ of chromosomes or 4 _pairs_ of chromosomes, but a total of 8 chromosomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @mgkrebbs commented, the left poster shows a total of 8 chromosomes, but only 4 ***pairs*** of chromosomes. I would dare say that you are right and that the poster is wrong. The left has 8 chromosomes, and 4 pairs of chromosomes. The right has 4 chromosomes, and they are not paired up, so the number of pairs is insignificant.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. We're looking for long answers that provide explanation, context, and include references to reliable sources. Don't just give your opinion; instead explain why your answer is right with appropriate citations. ——— Also note: from [answer] in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`* ———Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then delete or [edit] your answer accordingly.